# How to avoid Django shows multiple logs in shell

Tags: python, django

I have a part of codes like below in Django project.
This code gives the same multiple logs in the shell.

```py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('LoggingTest')
logger.setLevel(20)
sh = logging.StreamHandler()
logger.addHandler(sh)

# ~~~~~~

si_ids = Blank_Form.objects.get(blank_form_id__exact=blank_form_id).core_service_id.split('s')[1::]
logger.log(20, '[si_ids] {}'.format(si_ids))
```

> [si_ids] ['49', '69', '50', '56']

> [si_ids] ['49', '69', '50', '56']

> ... about 10 same line continues

Every line that has `logger.log` gives the same 10 more lines.

How to get just a single line of log?

Comment: What is the parameter `20` for inside your logger call?

Comment: This is it.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.log
I use it the same as `logger.info()`